# Finding angles of second and third order minima given only angle of first order minimum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, diffraction

For the following problem we are asked to find the second and third order minimums of a single slit diffraction experiment at $13^{\circ}$. I tried using the following $$\theta_p=p\cdot\frac{\lambda}{a}$$ by substituting $p=1$ and then using this to solve for $p=2$ which coincidentally worked. However this does not work for finding the third minimum. Note that the only information given is the angle of the first minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You were using a slightly wrong formula.
The intensity minima of [single-slit diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction#Single-slit_diffraction) are not located at
$$\theta_p=p\frac{\lambda}{a}$$
but rather at
$$\sin\theta_p=p\frac{\lambda}{a}.$$
You are given $\theta_1$. From this you should be able to calculate $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$.

Comment: Note that if the angles are small, these equations are approximately the same;  but as the angles get larger the approximation gets steadily worse.  This is why the OP's method worked OK for the second minimum but didn't give a good result for the third.